# Organizing scraped data into an array and selecting 1 or 2 Strings from the array

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to scrape certain values for different stocks from a table from finviz.com. I was only able to get an entire row so far and print it out. I would like to organize the returned values into an array so I can access them seperately.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class WebScrape {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ticker: ");
    String userInput = scanner.next();
            final String url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + userInput;

    // Get data


    try {
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        for (Element row : document.select("table.snapshot-table2 tr")) {
            if (row.select("td.snapshot-td2:nth-of-type(10)").text().contentEquals("")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                final String data = row.select("td.snapshot-td2:nth-of-type(10)").text();

                System.out.println(data);
                {

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

}
}
```

Now when you run this you get an entire row. I do not know how to get the returned values into an array and how to access the second value into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an ArrayList and with each iteration add your result. Then just get the 2nd result like you would in any array, at index 1:

```
    // Get data
    try {
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element row : document.select("table.snapshot-table2 tr")) {

            // continue was unnecessary here, just invert the condition
            if (!row.select("td.snapshot-td2:nth-of-type(10)").text().contentEquals("")) {
                String data = row.select("td.snapshot-td2:nth-of-type(10)").text();
                dataArray.add(data);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(dataArray.get(1));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to hel with this, I appreciate it. This is exactly what I wanted!